# Determining Probability With Several Pieces of Given Information

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I am looking at a probability question in which there are 2 pieces of information for each object, and only 1 piece of information is given to the reader.

There are wires, gears, and bulbs.
There are 3 of each, one of each color - red, yellow, blue, so 9 objects total.

3 of the 9 objects are placed into a bin.

We, as an observer, are told the following statement.
"The bin contains one bulb."

What is the probability that the the bin also contains at least another bulb?

I believe what is confusing me is the initial statement.
This is how I am approaching the problem.

Let event E  = The bin has 1 bulb.

Let event A = We have exactly 2 bulbs.

Let event B = We have exactly 3 bulbs.

I know I must calculate 
Pr[A|E] + Pr[B|E]

However, I am struggling to determine Pr[E]. I know the probability space for Pr[E] is $ \binom{9}{3}$, because these are the potential groups of 3 items in the bin we can have.
Would valid outcomes for Pr[E] consist of those that contain 1, 2, or 3 bulbs, or only those that have 1 bulb? (Technically, wouldn't a bin that has 2 or 3 bulbs also have 1 bulb?)

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!  I understand exactly what the question asks, but the counting of cases seems to be tripping me up a bit.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ${9\choose3} = \frac{9*8*7}{6}=84$ ways to get 3 items.

There are ${6\choose 3} =20$ ways to get 3 items that do not include at least 1 bulb.

So, there are $84-20=64$ ways to get at least 1 bulb.

There are ${3\choose1}*{6\choose2} = 45$ ways to get exactly 1 bulb

So: there are $64-45=19$ ways to get 2 bulbs or more.

(sanity check: there are ${3\choose2}*{6\choose1}=18$ ways to get exactly 2 bulbs, and there is $1$ ways to get all 3 bulbs ... $18+1=19$. Check!)

So, the probability of getting 2 or more bulbs given that you got at least 1 is $\frac{19}{64}$

Or, in terms of your events:

$P(E) = \frac{64}{84}$

$P(A|E) = \frac{18}{64}$

$P(B|E) = \frac{1}{64}$

$P(A|E) + P(B|E) = \frac{19}{64}$

Comment: Wouldn't there be (9 choose 3) ways to get 3 items?  These items are being chosen from 9 total and placed into a bin in which only the end state matters, so having item 1, 2, and 3, is the same as having item 3, 2, and 1.  Wouldn't 9*8*7 be over-counting the ways you can have 3 of 9 items contained in a bin?

Comment: @user7090180 You're absolutely right ... everything needs to be divided by 6 ... I'll edit!